# Expected Option Payoff equal to 0

Tags: option-pricing

How much would you sell an option whose expected payoff equals 0?

Comment: The fair, no-arbitrage price would be zero if the risk-neutral expectation of the discounted payoff is indeed zero.

Comment: What kind of option, which is not a combination of options, would have expectation zero?

Comment: A similar question that I have is "If this zero expectation is a result of a payoff function that pays X dollars in a set with zero mass (e.g a countable set of points) in a continuous domain, then would this option be sold at zero dollars?"

Comment: Are we assuming that all possible payoffs of the function are non-negative? Or could the option's payoff be something like -100 with probability 1% and 1.01 with probability 99%?

Comment: @alexbougias I'd argue that in practice prices are discrete and not continuous.

Comment: @DimitriVulis I would say that is "an option on a fair bet"

Answer (score 3):

For as little as people are willing to pay (as long as it’s a positive amount).